# IF statement in script and in a single command line

Tags: bash, if-statement

My script below checks for the instance of opened window in X server and it prints some info in the terminal depending on the state.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -z $(xwininfo -tree -root | grep whatsapp | grep chromium) ]]
then
        echo "IT DOES NOT EXIST";
else
        echo "IT EXIST";
fi
```

When I try to rewrite this into a one line terminal command I do it like this:

```
if -z $(xwininfo -tree -root | grep whatsapp | grep chromium); then echo "IT DOES NOT EXIST"; else echo "IT EXIST"; fi
```

this returns error and a wrong state...

```
bash: -z: command not found
IT EXISTS
```

Does anyone have any advice? I tried asking the [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) but it says I have everything in order...

Comment: Why are you getting rid of the `[[` and `]]` when putting it all on a single line?

Comment: Because that stupid web application said it is ok. Try it :D Now it is working because I added the parenthesis... Thank you. =)

Comment: Or just use `test -z …`.

Comment: @71GA, in this case it's a matter of you not reading its advice carefully, as opposed to the advice being wrong. You really *don't* need the `[[ ]]`s, but that doesn't mean that taking them out and leaving everything else identical is the only change to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got messed with an online bash code checker which stated that `[[` and `]]` are not needed. This worked for me:

```
if [[ -z $(xwininfo -tree -root | grep whatsapp | grep chromium) ]]; then chromium --app=\\"https://web.whatsapp.com/\\"; fi & if [[ -z $(xwininfo -tree -root | grep skype | grep chromium) ]]; then chromium --app=\\"https://web.skype.com/en/\\"; fi & if [[ -z $(xwininfo -tree -root | grep Viber) ]]; then viber; fi
```

Comment: Pay attention that you need backslashes like `\\"` to escape the quotations when using `chromium --app="..."` command. This command doesn't work completely fine withouth escaping the quotation.

Answer (score 4):

Correctly following the advice from http://shellcheck.net/ would have looked like the following:

```
if xwininfo -tree -root | grep whatsapp | grep -q chromium; then
    echo "IT DOES NOT EXIST";
else
    echo "IT EXIST";
fi
```

...thus, in one-liner form:

```
if xwininfo -tree -root | grep whatsapp | grep -q chromium; then echo "IT DOES NOT EXIST"; else echo "IT EXIST"; fi
```

---

See the wiki page for [SC2143](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2143), the shellcheck warning you received.

Comment: Definitely helped me in what I was doing. Ta!